# Vector direction equations

Tags: math, vector

I have three vectors in 3D space, one is a light source, one is a ray and one is the point on a circle a ray hits. With this information, how can I work out the vector which points back at the light source from the point the ray hits the circle?

Comment: Do you mean 2 coordinates and 1 vector? Can't you just inverse the vector?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. It would be clearer if you used either some more mathematical notation, or a picture.

Answer (score 1):

What you really have is two points (light source, circle intersection), and a vector between them, right? The vector is already implied by the two points -- it's the intersection coordinates minus light source coordinations. To reverse it, just negate all the coordinates of the vector!

Comment: Sorry, no there are 3 points. It is part of a ray tracer, so I have the ray into the screen, the point it hits the sphere and a light source. I need to know how to work out the vector from the point of intersection to the light, however I am useless with vectors..

Comment: The answer is still that you subtract the intersection coordinates from the light source coordinates. That gives you the vector from intersection to light.